# Sent ether from wallet to bittrex, 12 hours later no balance on bittrex

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, ether, exchanges

So I made an account on bittrex and I created a hex address so I could transfer over my ether, I went into my wallet and sent 0.1 ether to bittrex, 12 hours later my bittrex account still shows a 0 balance. Anybody got any ideas what I did wrong??

Comment: Maybe there is a minimum deposit amount over at bittrex?

Comment: Minimum deposit is 0.1 before it registers.

Answer (score 8):

The first thing to check is whether the transaction shows up on a ether block explorer. Enter your bittrex deposit address in the search field in https://etherchain.org .

If you see a balance,it may be that bittrex only shows you the deposits if the balance is above a minimum size.

Comment: Awesome man, checked the block explorer and it does show the 0.1 ether i deposited, i guess ill just try putting more in now.

Comment: Good to hear that your 0.1 ETH was transferred correctly.

Answer (score 4):

So this problem just fixed itself after I waited a little longer, took about 48 hours to show up.

Answer (score 0):

If the last comment is true, there is a serious problem with Bittrex: Indeed, they recommend a very small deposit to test the transaction. So 0.1 Eth may come to mind as "small deposit". If the amount is not show, there should be another reason. The accuracy of the wallet's assets is indeed of 10 unit over 1 billion: 0.00000001